# How to take control of subprocess socket?

Tags: python, sockets

So basically, i want to create process with `subprocess` module, i also want to take control of packets.

What i mean ?

---

Consider this code.

```py
import socket
client = socket.socket()
client.connect((..., ...))

client.send("e".encode())
client.close()
```

(Pretend that filename is `client.py`)
What i want to do here, is i want to make another python file, run `client.py` with `subprocess` module, and i want to listen in the parent process what packets it is being sent, and i want to modify them, basically tamper child process socket's packet, if that is ever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. It's essentially what a debugger does.

At the system/binary level, there is a system call `ptrace(2)` which allows a process to control another process. That includes setting breakpoints in the controlled process, stopping it, continuing it, modifying data in it, and so forth. To operate it from a python program, there is this module: https://python-ptrace.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

You could also debug at the python statement level. This is what the python debugger module (`pdb`) does. I don't know the best way to invoke this in such a way that you can run it programmatically but I'm sure that's possible. (At worst, you could simply run the interactive debugger and pipe commands into it.)

Both of these options, however, will have significant learning curves. At a high level, you would set a breakpoint in the sub-process so that the program stops at some point before the `send` system call is executed. When the breakpoint is triggered, you can then examine the buffer contents and/or replace them with your own, then allow the program to continue.

Comment: I think this is what i need, but python-ptrace does not have support for Windows, is there other package that does same thing but have support for Windows ?

Comment: Oh well, as it seems that PTRACE is for Unix and is not such thing in windows, im off to just making my own equalivent instead of taking control of existing program and wrapping it, then tampering it there, Thanks anyway.